# How to use wkhtmltopdf in ASP.Net page that requires users to be logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have created a simple ASP.Net page to create self printable tickets so non-technical people can change the text and layout of a ticket. Obviously the user has to be logged in to be able to print their tickets.

When providing the URL for wkhtmltopdf to convert, the tickets are not created because wkhtmltopdf does not have a session to prove the user is logged in.

Is it possible to pass the session to wkhtmltopdf in the URL, or is their a better solution?

Comment: How and when are you calling wkhtmltopdf? Can the users print the ticket if they are not logged in? if the answer is "No" then why do you have to worry about calling wkhtmltopdf when they are not logged in?

Comment: @Shoban wkhtmltopdf loads the page, takes the html produced in the page and creates a pdf. The page that is loaded by wkhtmltopdf needs to check to make sure the user is logged in, otherwise anyone could just load the page and create fake tickets.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is an exe right? how can they run it without logging into the server?

Comment: @Shoban wkhtmltopdf is not required to load the page. wkhtmltopdf loads a url passed to it and creates a pdf file. If I allow users to view the tickets page without being logged in, a user could load the tickets page and just print it or even use their own install of wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Exactly. Its your asp.net app which has to be secure not exe.

Comment: @Shoban Yes that's correct, and my ASP.Net is secure that's why the ticket never creates an actual ticket, just a PDF stating you must be logged in. This is the whole reason for wanting to pass the session, so that the ASP.Net page knows which user loaded the page, if they are logged in wkhtmltopdf will take the resulting HTML and create the PDF ticket(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass on sessions via URL, however, that's kind of unnecessary.

Usually, you do something like:

> > http://xyz.com/tickets.php

Would contain:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="ticket.php?ticket=1">Ticket 1</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="ticket.php?ticket=2">Ticket 2</a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="ticket.php?ticket=N">Ticket N</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And `ticket.php`:

```
<?php
    if( User->logged_in() ){

      $temp='C:\\windows\\temp\\tmp123546.html';

      file_put_contents($temp,'ticket html stuff');

      shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf.exe file:///'.str_replace('\\','/',$temp));

    }
?>
```

**Note:** I know you asked about this in ASP, but I don't know much about it. However, the above info should be true to any web-based software, be it ASP, PHP, Ruby or Python.

Comment: I don't think the exact solution you provided will work given that the tickets are personalised, ie they have the user name and unique id/barcode etc. Also the website runs on a web farm (multiple web servers), and the sometimes the user will swap servers. However your post has given me enough to go on to solve the problem. If I create a page that creates the tickets then saves it self as html add calls wkhtmltopdf to convert the resulting pdf as a single page I can get around the problem. It's horrible separation of concerns, but it will work.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it should work out. However, I also suggest using the wkhtmltopdf php class for googlecode. Should make this concept easier.